# Laravel eloquent query 20 latest records in after an id?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have an id of a record. I need to query 20 latest records updated before the record with the id.

Something like this

```
$orders = Order::latest('updated_at')->take(20)->before(id)->get();
```

I am using laravel5.5

**Edit**

Looking at the answer I feel my question is not clear enough.

Say this is my db table and id i have is 5

```
---------------------------------
|id| name | updated_at          |
|--|------|---------------------|
|1 |a     | 2017-09-21 06:27:59 |
|2 |b     | 2017-09-19 06:20:29 |
|3 |c     | 2017-09-12 05:27:59 |
|4 |d     | 2017-09-18 05:17:39 |
|5 |e     | 2017-09-17 06:27:48 |
|6 |b     | 2017-09-19 06:27:59 |
|7 |f     | 2017-09-04 06:27:58 |
|8 |g     | 2017-09-06 06:27:14 |
```

I want most recent updated records so

```
---------------------------------
|id| name | updated_at          |
|--|------|---------------------|
|1 |a     | 2017-09-21 06:27:59 |
|2 |b     | 2017-09-19 06:20:29 |
|4 |d     | 2017-09-18 05:17:39 |
|5 |e     | 2017-09-17 06:27:48 |
|3 |c     | 2017-09-12 05:27:59 |
|6 |b     | 2017-09-09 06:27:59 |
|8 |g     | 2017-09-06 06:27:14 |
|7 |f     | 2017-09-04 06:27:58 |
```

Now 20(in this case all) records updated before record with id 5

```
---------------------------------
|id| name | updated_at          |
|--|------|---------------------|
|3 |c     | 2017-09-12 05:27:59 |
|6 |b     | 2017-09-09 06:27:59 |
|8 |g     | 2017-09-06 06:27:14 |
|7 |f     | 2017-09-04 06:27:58 |
```

This is the result i need.

Comment: And what is the problem? Does it work?

Comment: it does not work. `before` is not a real eloquent function. I am asking is there a function that works like this. or any other way to achive this

Comment: Try order them by id then limit them by 20.

Comment: So something like (pseudo) `latest('updated_at')->orderBy('id')->take(20)->get();`

Comment: you select wrong answer , you can check , on Order::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
you fetch all data from db to php , on large data (memory overflow)

Comment: if performance is important for you must set an index on updated_at, on all fields you sort data by , you must set index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use query like this

```
select * from yourtable as t
inner join (
    SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE id = 590  
) as tm
on t.updated_at < tm.updated_at order by t.updated_at desc
limit 10
```

with eloquent orm:

replace 590 with your id

```
$orders = Order::join(
        \DB::raw(
            '(select updated_at AS ddd from orders where id = 590) AS t'),
        't.ddd',
        '>',
        'orders.updated_at'
    )->latest('updated_at')->take(20)->get();
```

Comment: there is small error in your eloquent code remove 'desc' from `latest('updated_at', 'desc')`. even after that it always returns all records.

Comment: thanks. after the edit this is the best solution to my problem

Comment: please check this condition on your data '>', on similar second you got some data , i suggest you use >=  and exclude  590 from them

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$id;
$num = 20;

$orders = Order::where('id', '<=', $id - $num)
               ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
               ->take($num)
               ->get();
```

Or

```
$id;
$range = 20;
$query = [];

foreach (range($id - $range, $id) as $idNumber) {
    $query[] = $idNumber;
}

$orders = Order::find($query)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent

If by the chance you where doing complex queries in Laravel you would want to use the DB class https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions

Comment: missed one word but uses Laravel Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see if it does what you're after

```php
$orders = Order::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

$index = $orders->search(function (Order $order) {
    return $order->id === 5;
});

$orders = $orders->splice($index+1, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks this did what i wanted.

Comment: on heavy data your server down

Comment: That’s right - with large number of records this might not be ideal. In that case I would probably suggest 2 queries - first to obtain the record index and the other to fetch collection with offset and limit or try to do it all using one statement with sub query.

Comment: yeah , i using subquery , on one statement , can seperate into two query , firstly fetch record by $recordex = Order::find(x), secondly get  Order::where('updated_at','<',$recordex->updated_at)->latest('updated_at')->take($limit)->get()